# What is the use of maintenance plans in SQLSERVER2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, maintenance-plan

What is the need and use of sqlserver maintenance plans and how to configure them?

Comment: Try asking on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Google explains all: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/creating_backup_jobs_p1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

They make it easier to create scheduled backups, reindexing and other maintenance tasks. Its a simple wizard that asks you what you want to do, to which databases and how often.

Answer (score 1):

### [Maintenance plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658.aspx)

> Maintenance plans create a workflow of
>   the tasks required to make sure that
>   your database is optimized, is
>   regularly backed up, and is free of
>   inconsistencies. These maintenance
>   tasks can be run manually or
>   automatically at scheduled intervals.
>   -- Source:MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance Plan provides you native tools that will keep your SQL Server up and running. You can schedule tasks such as Index maintenance, database backup, etc through a Maintenance Plan (see SQL Server Agent also). Check the twin site of StackOverflow, ServerFault, for related questions. I have seen gurus at ServerFault responding to queries similar to this. Check out http://sqlserverpedia.com/ you can find useful information in the site. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, maintenance plans are a basic tool for automating specific SQL Server administrative tasks by using SQL Server Integrations Services (SSIS) components.

Typical usage scenarios include:

- Index Optimization
- Database Backups
- Job History Cleanup

They also handle the creation of ancillary components such as jobs and schedules.

If you have a straightforward or simple database platform then maintenance plans can usually accommodate all of your needs. Database Administrators (DBA’s) of more complex environments usually prefer to implement their own custom solutions for these scenarios.